# Weird error in R using Sqldf - Same query, different results

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I'm getting a very strange result using the sqldf package in R.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
query == query2
b <- sqldf(query2)
print(row.names(b))
a <- sqldf(query)
print(row.names(a))
```

And the resulting log returns:

```
query == query2
[1] TRUE
> b <- sqldf(query2)
> print(row.names(b))
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26"
[27] "27" "28" "29" "30" "31" "32" "33"
> a <- sqldf(query)
> print(row.names(a))
character(0)
```

How is it possible that even though both query are exactly the same I'm getting a different result both times? The only difference is that "query" is generated procedurally while "query2" is just a copy and paste of "query" onto a differently named variable

I'm going to try reinstalling Rstudio for now, but I'd like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Reinstalling Rstudio didn't work.

Comment: Also, the code works perfectly at a colleague's PC

Comment: Updating R to version 3.4.4 did nothing either